# MYSQL - How to get cross results with multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables with different data except 1 column that contains the same IDs in both tables.

I made 1 query by table that give me different results.

- Table 1: The first query returns the list of COLUMN_IDs that appear more than
  X times in the results.
- Table 2: The second query returns the
  COLUMN_IDs that start by the same first letters.

I want to merge that 2 queries in order to get a list of the cross results.

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT COLUMN_ID, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM `TABLE1` GROUP BY COLUMN_ID HAVING cnt > X
UNION
SELECT COLUMN_ID FROM `TABLE2` WHERE COLUMN_ID LIKE 'ABC-%'
```

How can I get the COLUMN_IDs displaying only the ones with a number of result superior to 10 and beginning with 'ABC-%' ?

Thank you.

Comment: can you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following

```
select  COLUMN_ID from TABLE2 where  COLUMN_ID LIKE 'ABC-%'  and COLUMN_ID in 
(SELECT COLUMN_ID FROM `TABLE1` GROUP BY COLUMN_ID HAVING count(*) > X)
```

Replace `X` with the min number you want.

Comment: It worked fine. Thank you very much. I can't upvote yet but I would have. :)

Comment: @JulieHumbert - You're welcome :) .  Please accept correct answer, so others can use that solution.

Answer (score 0):

A join should work.

```
select a.column_id, count(*) as cnt
  from table1 a
  join table2 b
    on b.column_id = a.column_id
 where b.column_id like 'ABC-%'
 group by a.column_id
having count(*) > 10;
```